# Python - Decrypt from php openssl_encrypt

Tags: python, php, encryption

Question,
I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on this as i have been scratching my head.
Is it possible to build a decryption function in python to decrypt something that was encrypted using php with the below method of 128-CTR?

The php side was encoded using the following

```
$enc_method = 'AES-128-CTR';
$enc_iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($enc_method));
$crypted_token = openssl_encrypt($token, $enc_method, $enc_key, 0, $enc_iv) . "::" . bin2hex($enc_iv);
```

Where the token is the data getting encrypted.

I'd post a bunch of my trial code, but there's been too much and i'm not a super huge expert in encryption (The php side was built a while ago on an older version). I'm thinking i may just end up rebuilding it to the newer standards in python if i can make it somehow backwards compatible. Was just wondering if anyone had any links to otpics on this i may have overlooked, or some good book suggestions on the subject i can read more into to get better at it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code is wrapped in 3 backticks **`\`\`\`** not 3 single quotes :)

Comment: Recommendations for books etc are off topic. You should post your most promising Python code and describe the problem.

Comment: Yea, i kind of wanted to spare people from that horror as it's really not my strong suit. I was looking for more of a pointer if someone had a link hidden i may not have found yet. This was something i wanted to get a bit better at though so i think if i can't get it working with the backwards compatibility i will re write it with strong encryption using python completely. Just got into python, so i'm trying to learn as i go.  The books was a side question as i assume there are lots of people smarter than me on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using [pyca/cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/stable/).

```
import os
import base64
import binascii
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

crypted_token = "BuPVjqUgeGtXRT7OVsbjGZWRzZ3TEhZ3dSU4nyCtlA==::c6eda9c511d197d834cee4846fa726c3"
(ct, iv) = crypted_token.split("::", 1)
ct = base64.b64decode(ct)
iv = binascii.unhexlify(iv)

key = base64.b64decode("OqrcoKcA46oP6VpsMv14Kg==")

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(iv), backend=default_backend())

#encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
#ct = encryptor.update(message) + encryptor.finalize()

decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
plain = decryptor.update(ct) + decryptor.finalize()

print("Decrypted = {}", plain)
```

If there was a different library you had started working with that you'd like to use, feel free to post example code and we can help get it working.